# ASP.NET Core - Dependency Injection - IdentityServer4 DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I've been trying to find what the best/preferred way is to have my `RoleService` obtain a `ConfigurationDbContext` (IdentityServer4).

I would really like to decouple so that my RoleService can be testable.

The only way I found get access to the `ConfigurationDbContext` is via creation of a `public static IServiceProvider` in `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    // THIS IS THE PROPERTY I USED
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

    public ConfigurationDbContext GetConfigurationDbContext()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Startup(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = DbSettings.IdentityServerConnectionString;
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        var identityServerConfig = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddConfigurationStore(builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
                    options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
            .AddOperationalStore(builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
                    options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
            .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "certs", "IdentityServer4Auth.pfx"), "test"));

        identityServerConfig.Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ActiveDirectoryPasswordValidator>();
        identityServerConfig.Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, CustomProfileService>();
        services.AddDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ServiceProvider = app.ApplicationServices;
        // other code emitted
    }
}
```

**And then utilizing this code in** `RoleService.cs`:

```
public class RoleService : IRoleService
{
    public async Task<ApiResource[]> GetApiResourcesByIds(int[] ids)
    {
        ApiResource[] result;

        using (var serviceScope = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
            result =
                context.ApiResources.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
                .Include(x => x.Scopes)
                .Include(x => x.UserClaims)
                .ToArray();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to get a dependency in `RoleService.cs`?

Is there a way to abstract the `serviceScope` (since it is in a using statement, and probably IDisposable, I don't really know if there is a way to abstract obtaining a `context`?

Any other recommendations or best practices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a dependency to the `RoleService` by creating a constructor with the desired dependency as a constructor parameter.

Depending on the lifetime of your `RoleService` (can't tell based on the provided code) you would pass either the `ConfigurationDbContext` directly to the `RoleService` if the service is already `Scoped`. Or you would pass the `IServiceScopeFactory` to create a scope manually in your service.

Something like:

```
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

public RoleService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
{
    _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
}

public async Task<ApiResource[]> GetApiResourcesByIds(int[] ids)
{
    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
    }
}
```

Since your method is thight coupled to the DbContext (which isn't necessary a bad thing) you would probably end up creating an in-memory `ConfigurationDbContext`. 
The IdentityServer4.EntityFramework repository that you use has some examples for testing that [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/dev/test/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.IntegrationTests/Stores/ClientStoreTests.cs).

Comment: I&#39;m confused about how dependency injection should work here. If I have to create an instance of my Role Service manually from let&#39;s say a controller, don&#39;t I have to pass in the variable into the constructor? Or are we assuming that at some point, everything will feed into one another?

Comment: You shouldn't create an instance manually, that's what DI does for you. Inversion of Control (you don't want to know which type of instance you create). Therefore if you need an instance in your controller inject the `RoleService` in the constructor from you controller.

Comment: Great, that part is very clear.  I'm assuming though if I want to write some tests for the RoleService, they will need to manually create it, yeah?

Comment: Yes because that's when you want to test the `RoleService` and not the `IRoleService`

Comment: When testing RoleService though, do it directly, not through a Controller.